# How to add the payload to the root of a slice in the extraReducer in React Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-toolkit, toolkit

I created a slice with createSlice and in the extraReducer and want to add the payload to the root of this slice. I mean, if this slice is called "payments" and the initial state is an empty object ({}).
I'm trying to put all the payments inside this object, each one is an array, so it will be an object with as many payments as they are loaded.

```
const initialState = {};

const supportSlice = createSlice({
    name: "payments",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(loadPayments.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload.response);
            state.status = 'loaded'
        });
        builder.addCase(loadPayments.pending, (state, /*action*/) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
        });
        builder.addCase(loadPayments.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = action.error.message;
        });
    }
});
```

So, as this is written it makes an error because state has no "push" method. The solution I found is to assign a property inside this state:

```
        builder.addCase(loadPayments.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.allPayments = action.payload.response;
            state.status = 'loaded'
        });
```

And works, but it creates a state like:

```
MainState: {payments: { allPayments: {[],[],[], ... }, status: 'loaded' }
```

But what I wanted is to have:

```
MainState: {payments: { [], [], [], ... }, , status: 'loaded' }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the state format you want:

```js
MainState: {payments: { [], [], [], ... }, , status: 'loaded' }
```

You need to pass the `payments` property to `state` object, assigning `action.payload.response`:

```
builder.addCase(loadPayments.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.payments= action.payload.response;
  state.status = 'loaded'
});
```

I hope help!